# Regex to select path till a folder name

Tags: regex

Given a string `"C:\Tom\Dick\Harry\Chocolate\Treat\Hunt\Fruitless"` I have to select anything which appears before Treat.

I have tried with

```
   (.*)\\Treat
```

but it includes the Treat word also.

Result is `"C:\Tom\Dick\Harry\Chocolate\Treat"`.

Comment: You have to take the value from group 1, which is everything matched inside `(.*)`.

Comment: Example (PowerShell): `[Regex]::Match('C:\Tom\Dick\Harry\Chocolate\Treat\Hunt\Fruitless', '(.*)\\Treat').Groups[1].Value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a lookahead in the regex if you don't want to include the word `\Treat`.

```
.*(?=\\Treat)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fH6aO3/3)

**OR**

If you want to include the word `Treat` then try the below regex,

```
^.*?\\Treat
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fH6aO3/2)

Comment: Worked like a treat. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?)(?:Treat).*
```

This simple re should do it.

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/2)